# Executed SQL-Statement can't be viewed in SQL Server Profiler

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbctemplate

When I execute SQL statements without parameters I can see them in the profiler but when I set a parameter it just displays as `SELECT 1`.
Is there any explanation for this? Is there a switch where I can turn this feature on for parameters?

[image: profiler table]

Comment: Try to add events RPC:Started, RPC:Completed

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I overlooked it because my statement was surrounded by exec sp_executesql N'....' (Which was maybe added by some lib?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also capture `SQL:StmtStarting`, `Prepare SQL`, `Exec Prepared SQL` (in TSQL) and `SP:stmtStarting`, `RPC:Starting` (in Stored Procedures) events. With them you should capture all queries.

This `SELECT 1` isn't related to your parameterized queries. If it isn't something that you sent, then the JDBC driver could be executing them to check the connection or something similar.